# Jira/Java - injecting manager not working (setter)

Tags: java, jira

I'm building a plugin for Jira. I want to add a caching-layer so I wanted to use the `com.atlassian.cache.CacheManager`. I have to inject this via an argument / setter.

Since I'm extending an other class I wanted to inject this via a setter, but for some reason it returns **null** all the time.

```
import com.atlassian.cache.Cache;
import com.atlassian.cache.CacheLoader;
import com.atlassian.cache.CacheManager;
import com.atlassian.cache.CacheSettingsBuilder;

public class Foo extends AbstractJiraContextProvider
{
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    public void setCacheManager(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        //It does not get past this function..
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Map getContextMap(ApplicationUser user, JiraHelper jiraHelper) {


        cache = this.cacheManager.getCache("bar");

    }
}
```

I also tried this by doing the following:

```
public Foo(CacheManager cacheManager) {
    this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
}
```

After that the plugin does nothing anymore. I do not get errors, but it just gives 0 output.

I used this for documentation: https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/writing-confluence-plugins/accessing-confluence-components-from-plugin-modules

And  https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-developer-faq/how-do-i-cache-data-in-a-plugin#HowdoIcachedatainaplugin?-Instructions

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentions JIRA, but the documentation links that you provide are for Confluence (and outdated).

If you're developing an add-on for a recent version of JIRA (7.2+) then injecting components is now handled by [Atlassian Spring Scanner 2](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-spring-scanner/overview), so everything works with annotations.

If you follow the instructions listed [here](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-spring-scanner/overview) then you should be able to inject components via a constructor like so:

```
@Component
public class MyService {
    private final IssueService issueService;
    private final InternalComponent internalComponent;

    @Inject
    public MyService(@ComponentImport final IssueService issueService,final InternalComponent internalComponent) {
        this.issueService = issueService;
        this.internalComponent = internalComponent;
    } 
}
```